# Change settings from outside a module

Tags: python

I think it's not possible, but I ask anyway, maybe I'll learn something.

Suppose I have a piece of a code, from an external module I want to use:

```
from __future__ import print_function

import webbrowser
import time

from .api import Twitter, json
from .oauth import OAuth, write_token_file
from .oauth2 import OAuth2, write_bearer_token_file

try:
    _input = raw_input
except NameError:
    _input = input

def oauth_dance(app_name, consumer_key, consumer_secret, token_filename=None):
    """
    Perform the OAuth dance with some command-line prompts. Return the
    oauth_token and oauth_token_secret.
    Provide the name of your app in `app_name`, your consumer_key, and
    consumer_secret. This function will open a web browser to let the
    user allow your app to access their Twitter account. PIN
    authentication is used.
    If a token_filename is given, the oauth tokens will be written to
    the file.
    """
    print("Hi there! We're gonna get you all set up to use %s." % app_name)
    twitter = Twitter(
        auth=OAuth('', '', consumer_key, consumer_secret),
        format='', api_version=None)
    oauth_token, oauth_token_secret = parse_oauth_tokens(
        twitter.oauth.request_token(oauth_callback="oob"))
    print("""
In the web browser window that opens please choose to Allow
access. Copy the PIN number that appears on the next page and paste or
type it here:
""")
    oauth_url = ('https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize?oauth_token=' +
                 oauth_token)
    print("Opening: %s\n" % oauth_url)

    try:
        r = webbrowser.open(oauth_url)
        time.sleep(2) # Sometimes the last command can print some
                      # crap. Wait a bit so it doesn't mess up the next
                      # prompt.
        if not r:
            raise Exception()
    except:
        print("""
Uh, I couldn't open a browser on your computer. Please go here to get
your PIN:
""" + oauth_url)
    oauth_verifier = _input("Please enter the PIN: ").strip()
    twitter = Twitter(
        auth=OAuth(
            oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, consumer_key, consumer_secret),
        format='', api_version=None)
    oauth_token, oauth_token_secret = parse_oauth_tokens(
        twitter.oauth.access_token(oauth_verifier=oauth_verifier))
    if token_filename:
        write_token_file(
            token_filename, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret)
        print()
        print("That's it! Your authorization keys have been written to %s." % (
            token_filename))
    return oauth_token, oauth_token_secret
```

I'm calling the interesting function like this:

```
twitter.oauth_dance("My App Name", CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET, MY_TWITTER_CREDS)
```

I would like to change the input method (see the beginning of the code, in the try block), but WITHOUT changing the code of the module. I want to do it from the user side.

Is it possible ?

EDIT:

A not working example:

```
import twitter

twitter.oauth_dance._input = None
# twitter._input = None


CONSUMER_KEY = 'hi'
CONSUMER_SECRET = 'hello'

MY_TWITTER_CREDS = './config/twitter_credentials'

if not os.path.exists(MY_TWITTER_CREDS):
    twitter.oauth_dance("My App Name", CONSUMER_KEY,
                        CONSUMER_SECRET, MY_TWITTER_CREDS)


oauth_token, oauth_secret = twitter.read_token_file(MY_TWITTER_CREDS)

tweet = twitter.Twitter(auth=twitter.OAuth(oauth_token, oauth_secret,
                                           CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET))

tweet.statuses.update(status='Hello, world!')
```

Comment: In this case you could say `modulename._input = custom_input`.

Comment: Hum, I don't think so. I tried. _input is not an attribute. It's just a variable.

Comment: What is a variable but an attribute of a namespace? It should work.

Comment: What do you get if you `print twitter.oauth_dance._input` before you set it to `None`?

Comment: I get an AttributeError. I think I'm not setting it properly.

Comment: You probably need to import it first: `from twitter import oath_dance`, then `oauth_dance._input` should have been initialised.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you could say modulename._input = custom_input

```
#my_module.py

def hello():
    print('hello')

_func = hello

def test():
    _func()
```

Test:

```
>>> import my_module
>>> my_module.test()
hello

>>> def goodbye():
...     print 'goodbye'

>>> my_module._func = goodbye
>>> my_module.test()
goodbye
```

Comment: I'm doing something wrong then. I can't manage to change the input function. You can see my edited question if you want. The call to _input always call the input() function, in CLI.